# Make text in the center of a div

Tags: html, css, helper

Thats not a div I want I just cant get to post it because it does not meet some requirement. I have never used anything like that before, just need help for a college project that requires programming.
I have this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n2NI.jpg)

I just want the text to be centered.
jsfiddle .net /etr1ok47/#&togetherjs=VfasppUOxh

Comment: Usually , you can adjust the `line-height` or `padding-top` in order to make it centralized vertically .

Answer (score 1):

using flex in `this-p` class:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: hello, it worked but then each circle got into one paragraph.. i tried removing <p> but they one overlay each other https://ibb.co/iZTjBd

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the top of your p element in css if you are needing the words in the circle to be vertically better centered.

```
p.this-p{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

If the problem is the p itself not centering in the li element then define the parent with display: table and the element itself with vertical-align: middle and display: table-cell

Comment: padding does not seem to take effect

Comment: What is display set to? p element should accept padding. Is the circular border applied to the p element or the container?

Comment: Look at the last part of my answer. You can apply vertical-align.

Answer (score 0):

Try applying the following to your containing div (.parent) and the wrapper around your text (.child).

```
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
.child {
  line-height: normal;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: child would be the -span?

Comment: Yes .child would be the span around the text you want to center vertically

Answer (score -1):

p.this-p{ vertical-align: middle; align: center}

Above is when you use p element with padding. Same is applicable for other element